# Topology generated by maps and subbase

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, open-map

Consider a family of maps $(f_t)_{t\in\mathbb{T}} : S\to S'$. I would like to define a topology making this family continuous. To do so, I consider a topology $\mathcal{U'}$ on $S'$ and I define the topology $\mathcal{U}$ of $S$ which consists of all the preimage of $f_t$ by an element of $\mathcal{U'}$. Clearly we have :

- $\emptyset$ and $S$ are in $\mathcal{U}$
- If $A_i$ is a finite family of $\mathcal{U}$, then $\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ : For each $A_i$ there exists $A_i^{'}\in\mathcal{U'}$ such that $f^{-1}(A_i^{'}) = A_i$ and we conclude by the property of the preimage which allows to invert union and function.
- If $A_i$ is a finite family of $\mathcal{U}$, then $\cap_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ : For each $A_i$ there exists $A_i^{'}\in\mathcal{U'}$ such that $f^{-1}(A_i^{'}) = A_i$ and we conclude by the property of the preimage which allows to invert intersection and function.

Now I would like to find a subbase of $\mathcal{U}$. My attempt is as follows :

Consider the family

$$
\mathcal{A} = \{ f_{t}^{-1}(A') : t\in\mathbb{T} , A'\in\mathcal{U'}\}
$$

Consider now $B\in\mathcal{U}$, we know that there exists $B'\in\mathcal{U'}$ and $t\in\mathbb{T}$ such that :

$$
f_{t}^{-1}(B')\cap S = B
$$

Since this holds for all elements of $\mathcal{U}$, we have shown that every element of $\mathcal{U}$ can be written as a finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

I would like to know if my attempt is correct please ? And if you have another way to find a subbase.

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Your $\mathcal U$ is not a topology because for $A\in\mathcal U,$ the $t$ such that $A$ is the preimage *by* $f_t$ *of* some element of $\mathcal U'$ depends on $A.$

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! To be sure I understand well my mistake : when I said "for each $A_i$ there exists $A_i^{'}\in\mathcal{U'}$ such that.." I should also add that there exists $t\in\mathbb{T}$ such that $f_{t}^{-1}(A_i^{'}) = A_i$ ? If yes I see the point ! If not I am not sure to understand my mistake ? Also I should precise that I want to avoid the topology $\mathcal{P}(S)$ if it is possible

Comment: Yes, exactly! ($\exists t\dots$). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=initial+topology

Comment: @AnneBauval I did not see the Wikipedia page and the question that already exists !  Thank you a lot for your help really !